# Save rich text in Rails from contentEditable divs?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have a Rails app in which users can create entries, similar to blog posts. Both the title area and the content areas are HTML5 contenteditable divs. I don't need to be able to save anything like bold or italics, I just need to be able to save paragraph breaks and commas, exclamation points, etc. When the user opens the entry again, it needs to display the entry as they wrote it, with all the correct breaks, etc.

Are there any gems or plugins of the sort that would help me accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, that you can't simply pass HTML from contentEditable div via form submission, so some JavaScript should be involved. Checkout similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355583/can-div-with-contenteditable-true-be-passed-through-form) and link in first answer.