# Make Django build contenteditable div for TextField instead of textarea

Tags: django, django-templates

In my Django 1.10 project, I have a model:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    notes = models.TextField()
```

...and ModelForm:

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):    
        super(ContactForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)   
        for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
            field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control input-sm plain'
            if field.required == True: 
                field.widget.attrs['required'] = ''

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ('notes',)
```

I have two questions regarding this:

1. Can I make Django render the `notes` field as `div` with `contenteditable=true` rather than textarea?
2. If yes, how do I automate the form.save() method?

The second question is a bit vague, so I would be grateful for a hint regarding the first question. I have read through the doc, but couldn't find relevant section :(

Comment: I know I'm super late, but I found this article online when I was needing this exact answer to your problem as well | [Article](https://the7bits.com/blog/how-to-develop-custom-widget-in-django/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Question 1: Render a field with a specific HTML tag

*In this case, `<div contenteditable="true">...</div>`*

You can customize the widget used to render a form field. Basically, when you declare the field, you have to pass the argument `widget=TheWidgetClass`. Django has a lot of [builtin widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/widgets/) you can use. But you can also define your own. To know how, you will find many resources on the Internet. Simply search for "django create custom widget" on a search engine, or on SO. Possible answer: [Django: How to build a custom form widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707192/django-how-to-build-a-custom-form-widget)

Since Django doesn't provide any official documentation on how to create custom widget, the smartest way would be to create a class inheriting [Django's TextArea](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/forms/widgets/#Textarea) and using a custom html template based on [original one](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets/textarea.html).

## Question 2: Automate form.save() method with such a custom widget

Basically, you have to make sure the value of the div tag is sent with other inputs values to the target view of your form, in POST data. In other words, you have to make sure the content of the div acts like the content of any form field.
Maybe [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355583/can-div-with-contenteditable-true-be-passed-through-form) can help you: one solution could be using JavaScript to copy the content of your div to a hidden textarea tag in the form when the user click on submit button.

Good luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

First one can be done by using jquery. Since django will load the textarea with id='id_notes'. So after that you can select the element and do whatever you want to.

And in second one you can redefine the save method by writing you own save function in forms.py Here is an [example](https://github.com/sroy8091/urlshortener/blob/master/shortcode/models.py) for a url shortener.
Save method basically, defines what you want to execute when something is being committed to database.