# innerHtml and for loop

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, contenteditable

i want to write a short code i have multi contenteditable divs and i use a function to put the value of the div to a textarea please check with me

```js
var myContentArr = ["myContent1", "myContent2", "myContent3", "myContent4", "myContent5", "myContent6"];
var hiddenArr = ["hidden1", "hidden2", "hidden3", "hidden4", "hidden5", "hidden6"];

function myFunction(){
    for (var i = 0; i < hiddenArr.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById(hiddenArr[i]).value =
        for (var i = 0; i < myContentArr.length; i++) {
            document.getElementById(myContentArr[i]).innerHTML
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure of what you're trying to do. Is the goal to copy values from hidden array to the matching content array elements ?

Comment: trying to use this >>>> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355583/can-div-with-contenteditable-true-be-passed-through-form