# contenteditable with form submission

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I have a `form` which has a table with one of the `td` element is `contenteditable`. When I click on the submit button I need to submit the edited elements on the form. I am basically using HTML + Python Flask framework.  Here is my Javascript code.

```
function submitchanges(){
      alert(id)
      document.getElementsByClassName('editableText').value = document.getElementsByClassName('editableText').innerHTML
      var list = document.getElementsByClassName('editableText').value
      document.myform.action="/Reschedule/"+id
      document.myform.submit();
      }
```

So I have my changed elements. How can I pass this elements to the script using form submission?

Answer (score 1):

You can't submit `contenteditable` fields in a form post, unless they are form inputs. You'll have to use Ajax/XMLHttpRequests to do this.

Somewhat relevant link:
[Using HTML5, how do I use contenteditable fields in a form submission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247702/using-html5-how-do-i-use-contenteditable-fields-in-a-form-submission)