# How to insert an active link to an input textbox?

Tags: php, jquery, html

Is it possible to insert an active link to an input textbox?

I tried using an `<a>` tag inside the value of html but its not working.

```
<?php $email = "<a href=\"example@link.com\">example@link.com </a>"; ?>   

<input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
```

It only returns the text without the hyperlink value.

Comment: need to learn about escaping quotes in strings

Comment: oh sorry. i forgot to escape the quotes. i already edited it. but is it possible?

Comment: what exactly are your expectations?

Answer (score 5):

A couple things are wrong here...

1. You're not escaping your quotes.  Therefore the PHP is invalid.
2. You're trying to put HTML inside a attribute, which is also invalid.

The only alternative I could see being used here is an HTML element with `contenteditable="true"` applied.  This makes it so an element (per say a `<div>`) can have it's content be modified.

```
<?php $email = "<a href=\"example@link.com\">example@link.com </a>"; ?>   
<div id="fake-email" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $email; ?></div>
```

Then see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247702/using-html5-how-do-i-use-contenteditable-fields-in-a-form-submission) if you're doing a form.

*Edit:*

If you're trying to do a form, then this is one example:

```
document.getElementById("form").onsubmit = function(){
    document.getElementById("email").value =  
    document.getElementById("fake-email").innerText || document.getElementById("fake-email").textContent;
}
```

While your form is:

```
<form action="..." method="..." id="form">
   <div id="fake-email" contenteditable="true"></div>
   <input type="hidden" id="email" name="email" />
</form>
```

Comment: There is no need to put a reminder in every answer you create to have user accept it

Comment: @charlietfl The OP is new, this is their first question, usually newbies don't accept answers without a notice.

Comment: they get reminded, still not a common practice to do what you are doing

Comment: @charlietfl [According to this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251288/dealing-with-an-answer-that-wasnt-accepted-maybe-because-a-user-is-a-newbie-in) it's okay to remind them.  There is no need to argue over this, so lets drop it.

Comment: @Xero http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251298/ states *"If you comment in this situation...*. They mean to comment and not place it in an answer. Therefore, placing a comment under the OP's question will suffice, if OP hasn't responded. Nobody's attacking you; we're just saying so please don't take things personally. I have many unaccepted answers myself, so I understand.

Answer (score 2):

No, it isn't possible. Input values will always be rendered as plain text. If the user doesn't need to edit the link I would just put it beside the input.

Otherwise you might want to look into WYSIWYG Editors. Links to two of the most popular below.

[TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/)

[CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape quotes when including it in your php variable.

```
<?php $email = "<a href=\"example@link.com\">example@link.com </a>"; ?>
```

You need to use a backslash when you're using double quotes.

Alternatively, you can write it as such:

```
 <?php $email = '<a href="example@link.com">example@link.com </a>'; ?>
```

If you start with single quotes, then you don't need to escape the double quotes. \

I strongly suggest you read up on escaping characters when need be.