# When using wp_editor in Wordpress, serialize is only returning the full form on the second submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, forms

I have a form which I'm trying to convert to AJAX using `serialize`. Most of the form is itself loaded by AJAX only when the user starts to type in the title field.

```
<form id="new_post" onsubmit="ajaxSubmit()">
    <input onclick="loadEditor()" class="editor" name="post_title" placeholder="Let us know what you're thinking - post something." />
    <div class="ajax_editor"></div>
</form>
```

Here's the code for `loadEditor`, which loads a page with Wordpress' TinyMCE editor in it.

```
function loadEditor(preloaded) {
    if(preloaded!=true) {
        jQuery.ajax({url: "post-editor", success: function(result){
            jQuery(".editor").attr("onclick","");
            jQuery('.ajax_editor').addClass('active');
            jQuery(".ajax_editor").html(result);
            jQuery(".ajax_editor").fadeOut(0);
            jQuery(".ajax_editor").fadeIn(800);
        }})
    }
    else {
            jQuery(".ajax_editor").fadeIn(500);
    }
}
```

And here's the code for `ajaxSubmit` (which currently only outputs to the console while I'm testing it).

```
function ajaxSubmit() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_elements = jQuery('#new_post').serialize();
    console.log( form_elements );
};
```

However, when `ajaxSubmit` runs, only `post_title` is passed to `form_elements` and `post_content` is present but empty. If I 'submit' the form a second time, it includes everything as expected.

If I then edit the content of the form and submit it again, it acts as if nothing has changed (`form_elements` logs to the console but shows the previous `post_content`); on a further submit it includes the new `post_content`.

However, if I change `post_title`, the form always submits correctly.

Is this because I've loaded the form in two segments, or is there something else at work?

Comment: It's confusing, do you submit too early? If you log `this.elements` in `ajaxSubmit` do you only have one element?

Comment: @romuleald - Both elements are there, just one of them's empty; a further hidden input called "intents" shows correctly on every submit. Is it the name of post_content that's causing an issue perhaps?

Comment: What is in `result`?

Comment: @romuleald - the html of a page with wp_editor in it; I didn't include it here as it's a multitude of nested divs.

Comment: And there's form elements with value inside?

Comment: @romuleald - Ah, not quite. That may be the problem. There's an editable `body` element instead: `<body id="tinymce" class="mce-content-body post_content post-type-page post-status-publish locale-en-us mceContentBody webkit wp-editor html4-captions" data-id="post_content" contenteditable="true"><p>Editable content goes here.</p></body>` - this works like an input if it's just a normal html form, but could this be causing the issue?

Comment: Ahh! ok, you have the answer here! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247702/using-html5-how-do-i-use-contenteditable-fields-in-a-form-submission

Comment: @romuleald - Awesome, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were actually two issues here, both of which were down to the wp_editor that WordPress generates.

Firstly, we were dealing with an editable body element rather than a proper form input, as spotted by romuleald in the comments.

Secondly, that body element was actually within an iframe, which I'd missed from my original question in not wanting to include all the generated html.

So, I added an input element called "ajax_post_content" to my form, and changed the `ajaxSubmit` function as follows:

```
function ajaxSubmit() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var wp_editor_iframe = jQuery('#post_content_ifr');
    var post_contents = jQuery('#tinymce', wp_editor_iframe.contents())[0].innerHTML;
    var form_elements = jQuery('#new_post').serialize() + encodeURIComponent(post_contents);
    console.log(form_elements);             
}
```

This didn't truly include the content in the form, but appended it to the serialized variable.

Answer (score 1):

Before calling $form.serialize(); you will need to call tinyMCE.triggerSave();

```
tinyMCE.triggerSave();
var data = $form.serialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

When trying to get content from TinyMCE you should use its api, as no inputs are directly inserted into the DOM.

from the official TinyMCE documentation:

```
// Get content of a specific editor:
tinyMCE.get('content id').getContent() 
//          ^ use '#new_post' instead of 'content id'
```

docs here: [TinyMCE - getContent](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.getContent)

Comment: Even the version in Wordpress?