# Use a DIV as an input

Tags: html, input

Sorry if this question is very basic, but I'm trying to get back into programming and I'm stuck with this.

I want to have text input into a `<div>` in HTML, but I don't want the default chat box that comes with `<input>`. I just want it to directly print to a location within the `<div>`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you trying to do this? https://jsfiddle.net/uLkuvc4m/

Answer (score 27):

You can use contenteditable attribute if you don't wanna submit its value to the server, just like this :

```
<div contenteditable="true">I'm Editable. Edit me!</div>
```

So that user can edit the text but it's not gonna be sent to the server and it's just a client side stuff.

But if you need to submit the value to the server you have to use TextArea or Input tag and remove the borders by CSS styles. Say :

```
<input id="myText" type="text" style="border:none; background: transparent; outline: 0;"/>
```

Comment: the problem with input is that overrides a lot of style. You may need to add `font: inherit`, `color: inherit` etc...

Answer (score 16):

**Use a `<div>`**

Make the div itself a text input (as you mentioned in the comments) by using [`contenteditable` attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp):

```
<div contenteditable="true" style="outline:0px;">Hodor!</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aph6g7bg/)

To get the value you can use jQuery `$("div").text()` or js `textContent`

To use the `<div>` inside a `<form>` add some js to wire it up. You can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247702/using-html5-how-do-i-use-contenteditable-fields-in-a-form-submission).

**Use a `<textarea>`**

You can also use a `<textarea>` if you hide some properties:

```
<textarea style="resize:none;overflow:auto;
        border:0px;outline:0px;background-color:transparent;">
    Hodor!
</textarea>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hcez96w0/2/)

To get the value you can use jQuery `$("textarea").val()` or js `value`

Comment: You are a lifesaver! Thank a lot. I have a design in which I had to edit the input box and also to highlight text upon '#' key down. I had been searching all kinds of hacks, and here it is, the solution simply sitting here in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The contenteditable attribute specifies whether the content of an element is editable or not. [Demo](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp)

```
<div contenteditable="true">Use me as input box, but i am not a part of form submit to server</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Arkius have you tried using  TextArea "http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_textarea"

Comment: Textarea also has a box around it. I want the div itself be a text input

Answer (score 0):

use **contenteditable** to edit, use **outline: 0** to remove outline

```
<div id="input" contenteditable style="outline: 0;">innerText</div>
```