# How do I pass contenteditable text to the server without using JavaScript?

Tags: html, forms, contenteditable

I have an HTML table. This table has a `contenteditable` `td`, so when the user clicks a button, the text on that editable `td` gets passed to my `POST` action on the controller.

I think is simple, but I don't know how to do it, and all the related answers that I found include JavaScript code. I think is unnecessary to this case. How can I do this with using form method in the view code?

This is my code on the view

```
<table class="table table-hover" style="white-space:nowrap;">
    <tr>
        <th>Campo</th>
        <th>Columna en Excel</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Nombre</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" title="editar"  > Nombre en excel</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Note that I'm using ASP.NET MVC Framework on the server side.

Comment: The reason this requires JavaScript code is because the content of `td`s doesn't get submitted to the server. With a standard form submission, only form elements (such as `input`) which are within the `form` element, and contain a `name` attribute will get submitted. When you use JavaScript, you're typically [copying the value of the `td` to e.g. a `hidden` form element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6247785/3025856), and then submitting that—or, alternatively, submitting the value to the server directly using AJAX.

Comment: One alternative that _might_ work for you is to put e.g. a `textarea` element inside of your `td` and then use CSS styles to make it look like a standard text block when it's not active, and then look like an input field when the user clicks on it. That would give you something comparable to `contenteditable`, while also ensuring that your data gets submitted with the form.

Comment: thanks everybody for the answers, i finally understand why i have to use javascript or add a text area inside the td.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use a textarea, there is no way you will find that submits anything to the server that is not part of a form. If you want to use something other than standard form elements you will need to use JavaScript. This is how forms work.